# Golang - Why always ItoA removes initial 0 while returning in string

Tags: go

I was trying to get integer length for asking a fixed length of pin and tried to converting integer to string and i got this problem, below is the example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    inter := 034567

    fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(inter))
}
```

Output

```
14711
```

Here is the golang play ground code: https://play.golang.org/p/r87zeRaoZ23

I want to know the reason how it's getting handled, and if there is a another solution to handle these kind of scenarios.

Comment: Prefixing a numeric constant with 0 denotes that it's in base-8 (octal).

Comment: Your pin should not be a number. It should be a string of numeric characters. Number types should only be used for things that you would do maths to. Would you add two pins together? For instance. Similar to telephone numbers. They are also not numbers. They are strings too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`034567` is an integer literal, more specifically an **octal** literal. Quoting from [Spec: Integer literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals):

> An integer literal is a sequence of digits representing an [integer constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants). An optional prefix sets a non-decimal base: `0b` or `0B` for binary, **`0`, `0o`, or `0O` for octal**, and `0x` or `0X` for hexadecimal. A single `0` is considered a decimal zero. In hexadecimal literals, letters `a` through `f` and `A` through `F` represent values 10 through 15.

Octal `034567` = `14711` decimal.

You can't have an `int` number preserving `0`s you provide in the source code. If that is a requirement, use other types such as `string`.

If you remove the leading `0`: `inter := 34567`, then output will be `34567`.